# Get SSL certificates expiration date using powershell on ubuntu machine

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, ssl

I'm trying to execute the following script on ubuntu machine using PS mode but it shows me nothing, I want to know how can I do have this date.
Below is the script that I have wrote:

```
$var = (Get-ChildItem /etc/ssl/certs)[0].NotAfter
Write-Host $var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't magically parse certificate files for you. Use the `openssl` command.

```
$cert = (Get-ChildItem /etc/ssl/certs)[0].FullName
$var = ((& openssl x509 -in $cert -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter').Split('=')[1]
```